# c generate function and call it

Tags: c, x86, runtime, code-generation

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define uint unsigned int
#define AddressOfLabel(sectionname,out) __asm{mov [out],offset sectionname};

void* CreateFunction(void* start,void *end) {
    uint __start=(uint)start,__end=(uint)end-1
        ,size,__func_runtime;
    void* func_runtime=malloc(size=(((__end)-(__start)))+1);
    __func_runtime=(uint)func_runtime;
    memcpy((void*)(__func_runtime),start,size);
    ((char*)func_runtime)[size]=0xC3; //ret
    return func_runtime;
}
void CallRuntimeFunction(void* address) {
    __asm {
        call address
    }
}

main() {
    void* _start,*_end;
    AddressOfLabel(__start,_start);
    AddressOfLabel(__end,_end);
    void* func = CreateFunction(_start,_end);
    CallRuntimeFunction(func); //I expected this method to print "Test"
    //but this method raised exception
    return 0;
__start:
    printf("Test");
__end:
}
```

`CreateFunction` - takes two points in memory (function scope), allocate, copy it to the allocated memory and returns it (The `void*` used like a function to call with Assembly)

`CallRuntimeFunction` - runs the functions that returns from `CreateFunction`

`#define AddressOfLabel(sectionname,out)` - Outs the address of label (sectionname) to variable (out)

When I debugged this code and stepped in the call of `CallRuntimeFunction` and go to disassembly ,
I saw alot of `???` instead of assembly code of between `__start` and `__end` labels.

I tried to copy machine code between two labels and then run it. But I don't have any idea why I can't call function that allocated with `malloc`.

#### Edit:

I changed some code and done part of the work.
Runtime Function's memory allocate:

```
void* func_runtime=VirtualAlloc(0, size=(((__end)-(__start)))+1, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
```

Copy from function scope:

```
CopyMemory((void*)(__func_runtime),start,size-1);
```

But when I ran this program I can that:

```
mov         esi,esp  
push        0E4FD14h  
call        dword ptr ds:[0E55598h] ; <--- printf ,after that I don't know what is it
add         esp,4  
cmp         esi,esp  
call        000B9DBB  ; <--- here
mov         dword ptr [ebp-198h],0  
lea         ecx,[ebp-34h]  
call        000B9C17  
mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-198h]
jmp         000D01CB  
ret
```

At `here` it enters to another function and weird stuff.

Comment: Side note: don't use names that start with `__`. They are [reserved](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html).

Comment: like this?  00125 68 00 00 00 00  push  OFFSET ??_C@_0CB@CFIEOPKP@?5?5?5?6?5?5?5time?3?$CFi?5?5?5?5?5length?3?5?$CFi?5?5?6@     ?

Comment: `end` was reserved by `std::end` then I changed those names.

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık What is it 0.0?

Comment: asm output of one of my c++ code.  VC++ 10

Comment: Using script language like lua could also be viable; it's written in pure C.

Answer (score 2):

```
void CallRuntimeFunction(void* address) {
    __asm {
        call address
    }
}
```

here address is a "pointer" to a parameter of this function which is also a pointer.

pointer to a pointer

use:

```
void CallRuntimeFunction(void* address) {
_asm {
    mov ecx,[address] //we get address of "func"
    mov ecx,[ecx]   //we get "func"
    call [ecx]      //we jump func(ecx is an address. yes)
    }
}
```

you wanna call func which is a pointer. when passed in your CallRunt... function, this generates a new pointer to point to that pointer. Pointer of second degree.

```
void* func = CreateFunction(_start,_end);
```

yes func is a pointer

Important: check your compilers "calling convention" options. Try the decl one

Comment: if this doesnt work, try changin first "mov" with "lea" instruction

Comment: Oh ops ,before it even wasn't step into function. The exception was raised is `violation reading location`. And after add those brackets ,it raised the same exception :S.

Comment: After changing `mov` to `lea` ,it entered to another function.

Comment: what is your compilers calling convention? fastcall? declspec? stdcall?

Comment: i think you should try same with the AddressOfLabel(sectionname,out) __asm{mov [out],offset sectionname};

Comment: I didn't changed it. using cdcel.

Comment: VC++ 10.0 ? Digital mars 4.0 ?

Comment: It's ok ,I browser the memory and it's copying perfect. But function scope can't reach it I think. VC++ 12

Comment: copying perfect with or without the change i mentioned above?

Comment: Without ,my only problem is that I can't call it. He only view me like undefined memory when I see in disassemble.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to invalidate the caches (both instruction and data) between the function code generation and its calling. See **self-modifying code** for further info.

Comment: I know about that one ,cause of that I tested `printf` that it's push and call.